# How to use SWIG with "using"

Tags: c++, ocaml, swig, oracle-coherence

I am attempting to use SWIG 2.0.4 on a C++ library, I have the following in my .i
file:

```
%module coh
%{
#include "coherence/lang.ns"
#include "coherence/net/CacheFactory.hpp"
#include "coherence/net/NamedCache.hpp"
%}

%include "coherence/lang.ns"
%include "coherence/net/CacheFactory.hpp"
%include "coherence/net/NamedCache.hpp"
```

I swig it with:

```
$ swig -c++ -ocaml -I/opt/coherence-cpp/include coh.i
```

But get the error message:

```
/opt/coherence-cpp/include/coherence/net/CacheFactory.hpp:31: Error: Syntax error in input(1)
```

Line 31 of that file is:

```
using coherence::run::xml::XmlElement;
```

Is the `using` keyword not supported? Is there a workaround for this, or should I just write a C++ wrapper of my own, and SWIG that instead? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I decided to [write my own wrapper](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/ocaml-bindings-for-coherence-with-swig/) (and in future, to take a different approach from the start).

Comment: The keyword "using" is very difficult to Google for!

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is supported (I use `using namespace std` all over the place in my SWIG projects). Maybe you're missing an include somewhere?

Comment: Hmm, those includes are enough to get my C++ test app to compile happily

Comment: Keep in mind that SWIG has its own preprocessor. Are you doing any `#define`s in your normal C++ project that you're not doing while running SWIG?

Comment: Nope, no `#defines` at all! There are some in the Coherence `.hpp`'s tho'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has this to say:

> Note the difference between the using directive and the using
>   declaration : the using declaration allows an individual name to be
>   used without qualification, the using directive allows all the names
>   in a namespace to be used without qualification.

(I'm guessing that) SWIG supports the "using directive" but not the "using declaration".

That is to say, you can use:

```
using namespace somenamespace::mynamespace;
```

But you can't use:

```
using somenamespace::mynamespace::MySymbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

`using` in C++ headers is a bad practice, as it gets propagated to other inclusions, so the fact that SWIG doesn't support them is not a big deal.

Better remove `using` in your headers, and continue to SWIG!

Answer (score 1):

SWIG does support "using declarations". Your syntax error needs further diagnosis. I suggest looking at the preprocessed output using

```
$ swig -E -c++ -ocaml -I/opt/coherence-cpp/include coh.i
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided in the end [not to use SWIG for this](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/ocaml-bindings-for-coherence-2/).

Answer (score 0):

SWIG 3.0.11 added support for C++11 type aliasing with `using` keyword.

https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/news/2016/12/swig-3011-released/